# CPickle performance mystery

Tags: python, pickle

I have python code where I have a continuous loop with a pickle load inside. I have 200 pickle files in the loop each about 80 MB each on an SSD drive.

When I ran the code I experienced that the performance of the pickle load fluctuates continuously: mostly at about 0,2s but at times it "pauses" for 4-6s debasing the overall benchmark of the process.

What could be the problem?

```
def unpickle(filename):
    fo = open(filename, 'r')
    contents = cPickle.load(fo)
    fo.close()
    return contents

for xd in self.X:
    tt = time()                
    xdf = unpickle(xd)
    tt = time() - tt
    print tt
```

**OUT:**

```
1.87527704239
4.30886101723
0.259668111801
0.234542131424
0.228765964508
0.214528799057
0.213661909103
0.215914011002
0.217473983765
0.225739002228
```

The way I created pickle files:
I have a pandas DataFrame with the column: 'name','source','level','image','path','is_train'.
The main data regarding the size is the 'image'.
I pickle it with:

```
def pickle(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as fo:
        cPickle.dump(data, fo, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: Why are you running these benchmarks?  What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: I try to train a convolutional network with the highest speed as possible. I have quite big data, so I have to preprocess it, pickle it and then unpickle it because of my limited resources.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're using pickle as a [golden hammer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GoldenHammer), or maybe it's just all you know.  I'd recommend using a lighter format like CSV or perhaps JSON.  Pickling takes *forever* because it has to support nearly every kind of Python object.  It has to call into the Python API and do lots of nasty refcounting etc.  OTOH, Pandas [can do CSV natively](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html), which I'm certain will be much faster and possibly take less disk space.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for your useful answer, I gave an up to you. Anyway I learnt at least 3 new things: pandas saving facility (doh), term of golden hammer, and the abbreviation like OTOH. :)) One question: In the mean time I altered my code so, that I save the image batch as a separate list but in one unit as a tupple with the pandas DataFrame(without image). What do you think, would be faster if I saved the images as part of pandas DataFrame like column 'image', i.e. pandas saving method is faster like pickle?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is terribly unclear (in particular, you should be giving us enough information to reproduce your test case ourselves), but it feels like GC pauses or memory defragmentation.

Pickle is a terribly inefficient format, and processing 16 gigabytes' worth of it is bound to cause some serious memory thrashing.

Comment: I don't really know, how I could make my question much more clearer but I make a try and thank you.

Comment: Tell us how to *make* Pickle files that exhibit the problem.

Comment: OK I did it, I hope that contains the information, which make my issue clearer.